# Angular 14 - Get error: Argument of type 'Date | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number | Date'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular14

In the Angular 14 project, I am implementing Search Filter Pipe
I have this code:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
  name: 'transferFilter'
})
export class TransferFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(row: any, f1: Date, f2?: Date): any {
    f1.toString().length == 0 ? f1 = new Date("1995-12-25T11:30:00.000Z") : f1;
    f2 == null ? f2 = new Date() :f2;
    if (f1 >= f2 || f1 == null) { return row;}
    return row.filter((x: { fecha: string | number | Date; })=>{return  new Date(x.fecha) >= new Date(f1) && new Date(x.fecha) <= new Date(f2)});
  }
}
```

However, I got this error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 4, '(value: string | number | Date): Date', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'Date | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number | Date'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | number | Date'.
  Overload 2 of 4, '(value: string | number): Date', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'Date | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | number'.ts(27
```

Then `f2` is highlighted in:

```
new Date(x.fecha) <= new Date(f2)
```

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a fallback date while defining the parameter itself, e.g.

```
transform(row: any, f1: Date, f2 = new Date()): any {...}
```

**Explanation**

As you have made `f2` an optional argument, typescript infers the type as `Date | undefined`

```
f2: Date | undefined
```

and Date constructor only expects either of `number | string | Date` hence the error

```
interface DateConstructor {
    new (value: number | string | Date): Date;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Issue**

It is due to f2 is `Date | undefined` type from here:

```
transform(row: any, f1: Date, f2?: Date)
```

With the below line it only assigns with the value when it is `null`, but it won't change the type

```
f2 == null ? f2 = new Date() : f2;
```

---

**Solution**

To solve it, you can cast `f2` to `Date` type:

```
new Date(f2 as Date)
```

---

**Suggestions**

1. For me, parsing a Date with a Date instance (`new Date(f2 as Date)`) seems redundant, you can simplify it as below:

```
return row.filter((x: { fecha: string | number | Date; }) 
  => { return  new Date(x.fecha) >= f1 && new Date(x.fecha) <= (f2 as Date) });
```

2. Use nullish-coalescing operator (`??`):

You can simplify this line:

```
f2 == null ? f2 = new Date() : f2;
```

with:

```
f2 = f2 ?? new Date();
```